# Swift/IOS - Cambiar font del title y subtitle en un MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estoy creando una UIViewController con un mapa de MapKit, y necesito copiar el diseño de unos pins hechos en android, como puedo cambiar el font del titulo y subtitulo de las MKAnnotationView para ponerlos igual que en android

Este es mi codigo:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

        let identifier = "Annotation"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "")
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        } else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        }

        return annotationView
    }
```

[image: Mapa de ios]
[image: Mapa de android]

Answer (score 0):

Debes sobreescribir el método de selección del pin en una nueva clase:

```
class Custom: MKPinAnnotationView {
    let titulo: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40))
    let subtitulo: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame:CGRectMake(0, 15, 80, 40))

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(false, animated: animated)
        //Aquí personalizas
        if selected {
            titulo.font = UIFont.init(name: "Rockwell", size: 20.0)//Fuente y tamaño
            titulo.textColor = .green//Color

            subtitulo.font = UIFont.init(name: "Rockwell", size: 20.0)//Fuente y tamaño
            subtitulo.textColor = .green//Color

            //Se agrega los labels al view.
            self.addSubview(titulo)
            self.addSubview(subtitulo)
        }
        else
        {
            titulo.removeFromSuperview()
            subtitulo.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Al momento de pintar los pins utilizas la nueva clase:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var newView = Custom.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Un Identificador")
    newView.titulo.text = annotation.title ?? "" //Agregas el título al nuevo pin
    newView.subtitulo.text = annotation.subtitle ?? "" //Agregas el subtítulo

    return newView
}
```